# append bytes in flex byteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, flex4, arrays

I have five video file like video-1.flv, video-2.flv, video-3.flv, video-4.flv, video-5.flv.
I read first video-1.flv and store it in a byteArray using the code below:

```
private var byteArray = new byteArray();
byteArray = readFile(VIDEO-FILE-PATH);

private function readFile(fileName:String):ByteArray
{
    var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var inFile:File = File.applicationDirectory; // source folder is application
    inFile = inFile.resolvePath(fileName);  // name of file to read
    var inStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    inStream.open(inFile, FileMode.READ);
    inStream.readBytes(data, 0, data.length);
    inStream.close();

    return data;
}
```

Now I want to read and store the next videos from video-2.flv to video-5.flv in the same byteArray.

How can I do this. Any code sample or web link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same byteArray for all files, data will be appended automatically, just pass the buffer to the `readFile` method and remove the `data.length` (in first reading it's 0, so you read all available data and in next readings this will course reading new file with the length of all previuse buffer) in `inStream.readBytes(data, 0, data.length);` line. Example:

```
var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
for(var i:int = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    readFile("video-"+i+".flv", buffer);
}

private function readFile(fileName:String, buffer:ByteArray):ByteArray
{
    var inFile:File = File.applicationDirectory; // source folder is application
    inFile = inFile.resolvePath(fileName);  // name of file to read
    var inStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    inStream.open(inFile, FileMode.READ);
    inStream.readBytes(buffer);
    inStream.close();

    return buffer;
}
```